# How to force the user to complete a task before pressing back?

Tags: android

I show to user a list of categories, he must choose one.
How to force the user to choose before pressing back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're asking the user to choose via a `Dialog`, use the `setCancelable(false)` flag. According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable%28boolean%29), that prevents the use of the back button.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this. Just handle the case when user doesn't select anything.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably override the handling of the back button, but the more correct thing to do is simply handle the cancellation. In your `onActionResult` override, only react if the `result` argument is `Activity.RESULT_OK` (it will be `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED` if the user pushes the back button).

Answer (score 1):

I would use a spinner and preselect a good default value.
Forcing the user to do something should be only the last resort in your application.